# WordPress array in query meta_value

Tags: wordpress

I have a website where I want to filter on items.

The url is `/?app=1`. I want to add an other item in the url like `?app=1,2`
and then query it with wordpress query.

I'm now trying to use this as follows

```
$app = $_GET['app'];

//* The Query
$rd_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'producten',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => '_product_application_list',
                            'value' => array($app),
                            'compare' => 'IN'
                        )
                    )
                );

                $exec_query = new WP_Query( $rd_args );
```

What is weird about this is that the above doesn't work. But when I'm using 
`'value' => array(1,2)`, it does.. how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, that might be as easy as changing

```
$app = $_GET['app'];
```

to

```
$app = explode(",", $_GET['app']);
```

Which will make sure that $app is an array (even if it has only one element inside when you just pass `?app=1`.
You'll need to change

```
'value' => array($app),
```

to

```
'value' => $app,
```

as well.
What you're doing now leads to you saying

```
'value' => array("1,2"),
```

which won't work because it treats the two values as a single combined value.

Comment: Janh2, thank you for your response, this helped me.. i already used that but with the array.. very good. thank you!